# I'm having trouble setting up SMTP using Office 365?

Tags: smtp, office365

I've been asked to set up SMTP using office 365. I've created a generic email account, given it a licence for exchange. I've enabled "Authenticated SMTP" in the user settings as well.

I've sent over:

```
E-Mail Address
SMTP Host: SMTP.Office365.com
SMTP Port: 587
SMTP Username: which is the email address
SMTP Password:
```

I've tested it on smtper.net and I keep getting:

```
"SMTP send error. The operation has timed out."
```

If I untick "Use Secured Connection", then I get an error message:

```
"SMTP send error
Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail \[YT3PR01CA0019.CANPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\]"
```

I'm sure I'm either missing something or I've not done something correctly.

This is the information I was sent from the original email:

```
\*\*SMTP Email Account Information
```

We would like to set up your email account details so that you are ready to go with our email notifications. Please can you set up a generic email account (e.g. portal@partner.co.uk) that we can use to enter the details into our system? We will need the following information:

```
Email Address
SMTP Host
SMTP Port
SMTP Username
SMTP Password\*\*

E-Mail Address
SMTP Host: SMTP.Office365.com
SMTP Port: 587
SMTP Username: which is the email address
SMTP Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could narrow down the issue to find whether the issue is with the MS end or your application end. Let's try to send an email via **PowerShell**. Here are the steps and commands.

Step 1: Connect with Microsoft Exchange

- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
- Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser
- Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
- Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName 'admin email'

Step 2: Send test email

- $cred = Get-Credential  –UserName  'which is the email address'
- Send-MailMessage -To "Any email address" -From "which is the email address" -Subject "Test Email" -BodyAsHtml "Successfull !!" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Port 587 -Credential $cred –UseSsl

Step 1 will download the Exchange module and connect you with the Exchange admin

Reference MS docs
[Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.2) , [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

If it is not successful please contact Microsoft to check your Tenant authentication status.